# Is seeking with _lseeki64() to the end of a file expensive?

Tags: c, io, seek

I'm writing an archive to file and it just so happens that writing the archive's table of contents last is the most simple.

For a large file (500 - 3000 mb), would seeking from the start of a file (after grabbing the 8byte address of the table) to the very end with `_lseeki64()` be expensive?  Or does seeking not care about distance all that much?

(If it matters, I perform my own file buffering since I'm not using stdio.h, though I imagine the harddisk may be performing buffering of it's own as well.  Also, the file is opened with _O_SEQUENTIAL set, though I suspect that hint doesn't really do anything to be honest)

Comment: As expensive as adding two numbers...

Comment: well, it *might* depend on the filesystem as well.

Comment: Try it! In a loop open the file, start a timer, seek to the end, stop the timer and save the elapsed time, and close the file. Do the loop a million times. Check the accumulated time and the average time for the seek.

Comment: Ask yourself another question: What drawbacks does a TOC at the **end** of the file have? One thing that immediately comes to mind is you can't support streaming this file over the net, because you need the **whole** file to make sense of it.

Comment: why are you working with system level functions instead of C buffered IO?

Comment: @SergeyA - I need access to +2gb files, and don't want to use _ftelli64() (seen a few cases of it giving slightly wrong addresses on SO, and I need it to map perfectly byte for byte) and I don't want to use a library.  Buffering reads and writes wasn't hard.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - I profiled it and it doesn't appear to cost anything on my system, so that's a plus.  My main worry though is that this may not be the general case, since I use an SSD

Comment: @Anne Quinn it should theoretically be equivalent to calling `stat` on the file and then calling `lseek` with `st_size` on the open descriptor, so long as it's a normal file on a disk.

Comment: @Anne Quinn Additionally, it may be useful to incrementally write the table of contents with `pwrite`, although I don't know if that will work in your specific case. (And I don't know if that's available on Windows)

Comment: @beeselmane *so long as it's a normal file on a disk* Indeed.  I can imagine an [HSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_storage_management) where seeking to the end of a multi-gigabyte file forces the call to wait for the entire file to be read back from tape.  In that case, such a seek call could be horribly expensive.

Comment: _Posting_ the _code_ is more clear than _describing_ the code.  For better answers, post what you have done.  In particular, opening the file in binary mode can be less of a performance concern than opening in text mode.

Comment: Seeking on FAT is in no way simple :D

Comment: On classic Unix systems, the seeking would be very inexpensive — the recorded offset in the data structure identified by the file descriptor would be changed to a new number without touching the disk at all.  The next access (read or write) might be considerably more expensive (though not dreadfully expensive even so — on classic Unix systems).  The rules on non-Unix file systems might be different. If you're using `lseeki64()`, you're presumably on Windows; heed Antti Haapala's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45575029/is-seeking-expensive#comment78118698_45575029)